# UIImagePickerController crashing after deleting a photo

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

can't seem to find anyone else with this problem so here goes. I create my UIImagepickerview like so

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[picker setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(250.0f, 450.0f)];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[EditChoicePopoverController setContentViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
```

The first time i create it it works fine. I can grab images and do what i like with them. The problem comes when i quit my app, load up my photo library from outside the app and delete an image. Then when i open my app from scratch and try to open UIImagepickerview again it crashes with the error.

***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: ' -[NSOrderedSet initWithOrderedSet:range:copyItems:]: range {3, 2} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'***

Now i assume this is something to do with the table/expected values/ actual values given, but i have no idea what to do. Anybody know?

Comment: Does it matter what state your application was in when it went into background? I'm assuming that deleting image shorten certain array that your application try to access.

Comment: How about you dismiss the popup on viewDidDisappear?

Comment: i don't do anything in the viewDidDisappear, i assumed the imagepicker would take care of its self. Do i have to call some function that reloads the array or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement method [applicationDidEnterBackground:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground%3a) of your application delegate and release every object that retain a reference to those pictures.
 It is possible that, even if you quit the app, some references are kept alive to speed up the load when you resume the app.